# What's the correct way to check return value from `querySelectorAll`?

Tags: javascript, dom, document, selectors-api

When using `querySelectorAll`, what is the correct way to check if it returned any elements?

It returns something that can't be checked for `false`. This doesn't seem to work:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
if (elements) {
  // doesn't work, `elements` is always true
}
```

Right now I'm doing the following check via `.length` property:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
if (elements.length) {
  // querySelectorAll returned DOM elements
}
```

Is this how you do it?

Answer (score 5):

That's correct.

`document.querySelectorAll('.class')` returns a non-live [Node List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), this will always be *truthy*.

Therefore you need to count the items in the list by using `length` to determine if there are more than 0 items.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks, have updated my answer.. and knowledge!

Comment: No problems - be aware that it's specifically non-live, ie it's elements won't update.  In some cases you have live ones as documented on that page

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `querySelectorAll` will return an [array-like object](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/), which has a length property (the actual object is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)).

So,

```
if(elements.length > 0) {
  // you have elements
}

// and

if(element.length === 0) {
  // you don't have elements
}
```

The problem with doing `if(elements)` is that `[]` is truthy, meaning it will always return true:

`!![] === true`.